# How to fetch excel sheet data which is stored in another server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to fetch excel sheet data which is stored in another server URL like "http://www.Test.com/Test/Book1.xls" from my local asp.net web application.

Can anyone help me resolving this?

Comment: How about downloading it into a temporary location?

Comment: Without downloading i needed ...is that possible ?

Comment: Well as @Valin proposes you can download it as stream. But you will have to download it, as http does not support opening (for seeking etc.) files on a remote location.

Answer (score 1):

Here is controller example to get external file as Stream:

```
    public FileResult Index()
    {
        string url = "http://www.Test.com/Test/Book1.xls";
        WebRequest wrGetUrl = WebRequest.Create(url);
        Stream objStream = wrGetUrl.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        return new FileStreamResult(objStream, "application/octet-stream");
    }
```

Worked for my test file.